# Which of the following string have two or more parse trees?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, parsing

Consider the following ambiguous grammar:

$S→A|BC$

$A→aAC|B$

$C→bCc|c$

$B→aBb|\in$

Which of the following string have two or more parse trees?

1. $aaabbbbbcc$
2. $aaabb$
3. $aabb$
4. None of these

---

My attempt:

1. $aaabbbbbcc\notin L(G)$
2. $aaabb\notin L(G)$
3. $S=A=B=aBb=aaBbb=aabb$ in only one way.

> > Can you explain $L(G)$ and string in options have two or more parse tree, please?

Comment: There seems to be an error in your grammar, you have no $B$ variable.

Comment: @mrp, Thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your answer: the first two words aren’t in $L(G)$, and the third has a unique derivation (and parse tree). Thus, the correct answer is *None of these*.

The grammar is simple enough that we can identify the language. There are only two possibilities for the first step in a derivation. Suppose that we begin by applying the production $S\to BC$. We can apply $B\to aBb$ $k$ times for any $k\ge 0$, but eventually we must apply $B\to\epsilon$. Similarly, we can apply $C\to bCc$ $\ell$ times for any $\ell\ge 0$, but eventually we must apply $C\to c$. If we apply the productions in this order, the derivation is

$$S\Rightarrow BC\Rightarrow^k a^kBb^kC\Rightarrow a^kb^kC\Rightarrow^\ell a^kb^{k+\ell}Cc^\ell\Rightarrow a^kb^{k+\ell}c^{\ell+1}\;.$$

Changing the order of the applications of $B\to aBb$ and $C\to bCc$ does not affect the final result. This part of the language is easy to describe:

$$L_1=\left\{a^kb^\ell c^m:\ell=k+m-1\text{ and }m\ge 1\right\}\;.$$

Now suppose that we begin by applying $S\to A$. We can then apply $A\to aAC$ $k$ times for any $k\ge 0$, but the only way to get rid of the $A$ is eventually to apply $A\to B$; at this point we have

$$S\Rightarrow A\Rightarrow^k a^kAC^k\Rightarrow a^kBC^k\;.$$

We can apply $B\to aBb$ $\ell$ times for any $\ell\ge 0$ but must eventually apply $B\to\epsilon$:

$$S\Rightarrow A\Rightarrow^k a^kAC^k\Rightarrow a^kBC^k\Rightarrow^\ell a^{k+\ell}Bb^\ell C^k\Rightarrow a^{k+\ell}b^\ell C^k\;.$$

Each $C$ must eventually generate a word of the form $b^mc^{m+1}$, so in the end we get

$$a^{k+\ell}b^\ell b^{m_1}c^{m_1+1}\ldots b^{m_k}c^{m_k+1}\;,$$

where $k,\ell,m_1,\ldots,m_k\ge 0$. Note that here again the outcome does not depend on the order of the productions, though there can be many possible orders. This part of the language is

$$L_2=\left\{a^{k+\ell}b^\ell b^{m_1}c^{m_1+1}\ldots b^{m_k}c^{m_k+1}:k,\ell,m_1,\ldots,m_k\ge 0\right\}\;.$$

Now consider the word $a^3b^5c^2$. It’s not the case that $5=3+2-1$, so this word is not in $L_1$. Suppose that it’s in $L_2$. It has only one block of $c$s, so $k=1$; that block is of length $2$, so $m_1=1$. Thus, the word must be $a^{1+\ell}b^{\ell+1}c^2$ for some $\ell\ge 0$, which is plainly not the case, since $3\ne 5$. This shows that $a^3b^5c^2\notin L$.

Examination of $L_1$ and $L_2$ shows that only $L_2$ contains words without $c$, and then only when $k=0$. But the words in $L_2$ with $k=0$ are those of the form $a^\ell b^\ell$ for $\ell\ge 0$, so $a^3b^2\notin L$.

On the other hand, $a^2b^2$ is in $L_2$ but not in $L_1$, so it can be derived only via the first step $S\Rightarrow A$. Moreover, $k$ must be $0$, so the next step must be $A\Rightarrow B$. Finally, the production $B\to aBb$ must be applied exactly twice, followed by $B\to\epsilon$. At each stage there is exactly one non-terminal symbol, so no other derivation is possible. That is, not only does $a^2b^2$ have only one leftmost derivation, it has only one derivation of any kind.

The analysis used above to identify and describe $L_1$ and $L_2$ actually shows that each word of $L$ has a unique leftmost derivation: for both $L_1$ and $L_2$ I actually wrote down the unique leftmost derivations, though I did not go into detail for

$$C^k\Rightarrow^{m_1+1}b^{m_1}c^{m_1+1}C^{k-1}\Rightarrow^{m_2+1}\ldots\Rightarrow^{m_k+1}b^{m_1}c^{m_1+1}\ldots b^{m_k}c^{m_k+1}\;.$$

Thus, $G$ is not in fact an ambiguous grammar.

Comment: @Mithlesh: You're welcome.